# Determine the values of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ for which the system is consistent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Questions: please can you explain this question to me it is a matrix, i dnt know to use the website format to input the matrix . sorry for that

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&α&0&1\\
      0&1&β&1\\
      γ&0&1&1
    \end{array}
\right] $$  For which values of α, β, γ does the system have a solution? Are there values with a unique solution? If so, give all the values.

attempt: i tried to put the matrix in RREF form i got :

$$ \left[
     \begin{array}{ccc | c}
       1&0&-αβ&1-α\\
       0&1&β&1\\
       0&0&1+αβγ&1+\alpha\beta-\gamma
      \end{array}
  \right] $$

please i do not know how to continue. please explain it to me

Comment: so, for which value of a, b, p is the system consistent

Answer (score 1):

The system will fail to be consistent when $1+\alpha\beta\gamma=0$ and $1+\alpha\beta-\gamma\ne0$.